# BigQuery : Job is done but table not created yet

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently trying to run 2 jobs and one query through a script using the Google BigQuery API.

The two jobs involve loading into BigQuery two CSVs (compressed into GZIP) from Google Cloud Storage and creating two tables. We then run the query to create a third table using the two other tables.

To do this synchronously, I check the status field of the job response and when the state is DONE, I make my query.

Unfortunately even if the state is marked as DONE, the jobs are still running and the tables are not yet created, it seems like that what is done is only the loading into BigQuery from GCS.

Do you know a way to be sure that the tables are created using the job response ?

Comment: Are you certain that the job has completed successfully? (i.e. the status.errorResult field is empty). Can you post your job ids?

Comment: Hi Jordan, the job completes successfully and the table is created. My issue is that I get the DONE state way before the table is created. The job id is : job_psIg76wEeOh5uv2pTNDaoujrPi4

Answer (score 0):

Here is the timeline from what I can see from looking at the timestamps on the BigQuery metadata:

```
Job created (PENDING): 1408605297062 (as date: 08/21/14 00:14:57)
Job started (RUNNING): 1408605316228 (as date: 08/21/14 00:15:16)
Storage commit:        1408606029075 (as date: 08/21/14 00:27:09)
Table create:          1408606029075 (as date: 08/21/14 00:27:09)
Job end (DONE):        1408606029151 (as date: 08/21/14 00:27:09)
```

This looks like the job completion and table creation happen within a few milliseconds of each other. Does this not match with your observations?

Comment: Everything was working fine, my implementation was bad. I fixed it. Thank you for your time.